# Enable :hover on margin

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there any possibility to enable the :hover css effect also on the "margin area" of an object? I found a dirty solution working with an extra div inside, but is there something more elegant for this simple structure:

```
<ul>
  <li><a>Hello</a></li>
  <li><a>Hello</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
  list-style: none; 
  margin: 0px; 
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  margin: 5px 100px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

li:hover a {
  color: red;
}

#dirty {
  padding: 0px 100px;
  margin: 0px -100px;
}
```

Hey is my working dirty example: https://jsfiddle.net/equalsound/wn4ctxvh/

If possible, a css only solution would be lovely.

Comment: You can't use padding?

Comment: No, margin is outside of the element, not part of it. Border and padding are different.

Comment: No, due to an js library which is copying my original element, padding would make the element bigger which I don't want.

Comment: can you add a class to the item to override the JS library?

Comment: You mean to simply reduce the width of the item when being copied?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but doesn't this work? https://jsfiddle.net/wn4ctxvh/1/

Comment: In this example, where do you want the `:hover` to work? On the left and right of the grey boxes? If so, have you looked into pseudo-elements?

Comment: @Huangism No, u just changed my margin to padding, but it has to be margin.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen On the left and right side and when hovering over the grey area, so the "whole element"

Comment: Is [this the render](https://jsfiddle.net/esd0o2k2/) you're after? I'm not exactly sure by what you've told us.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen  Yes!! That was exactly what I was looking for, thanks :)

Comment: @equalsound what difference does it make? it looks the same as before. Is there an example you can give of why it doesn't work?

Comment: @equalsoud Great, added it as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As asked in the comments to your question, here is a working answer, using pseudo-elements to fill the 100px side margin:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none; 
  margin: 0px; 
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px 100px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

li::before,
li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
}

li::before {
  right: 100%;
}

li::after {
  left: 100%;
}

li:hover a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>Hello</a></li>
  <li><a>Hello</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you so much for relieving my headache! Life saver!!

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, an alternative using transparent borders that's a little less practical due to the use of `background-clip: padding`:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none; 
  margin: 0px; 
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  margin: 5px 100px 5px 0;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

li:hover a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>Hello</a></li>
  <li><a>Hello</a></li>
</ul>
```

Although, you can obviate the need for that if you can afford to make the `a` elements blocks and apply the background color to them instead:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none; 
  margin: 0px; 
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  margin: 5px 100px 5px 0;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

li:hover a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>Hello</a></li>
  <li><a>Hello</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is what you are aiming for, but maybe it could help:

https://jsfiddle.net/wn4ctxvh/2/

```
<ul>


 <li>
    <div>
      <a>Hello</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <a>Hello</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>




ul {
list-style: none; 
  margin: 0px; 
  padding: 0px;
}

li div {
  margin: 5px 100px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

li:hover a {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: No, sadly not. Like that, the width of the element is increasing what I don't want, it should stay the same hight as in my example