# CSS: Is there a way to not lose hover, if the mouse goes off for a split-second?

Tags: css, hover, liferay-7, megamenu, liferay-7.3

I'm creating a megamenu (opening with `hover`) and it'd be neat to not unhover, if the mouse goes over empty space for a split-second. The top bar buttons have a bit of space between them and moving mouse to the null-area will drop hover and hide the megamenu completely.

[image: Megamenu-example]
The white square in the image is the button area. Both it and light-blue dropdown area display the dropdown with `hover`. However, leaving these areas for a split-second (arrow) causes the hover to be lost and the menu will hide.

How can I get the menu to refocus and not hide? I've tried using `transition-delay`, but haven't yet got it working, as the menu works with `display: flex | none`. I use `display`, as there are four separate dropdowns in the megamenu, but is there a better way I should use?

I'm using Liferay 7.3.2, if it makes any difference.

---

EDIT: Some of my code:

```html
<ul id="megamenu-top">
    <li class="megamenu-top-item">
        <button class="megamenu-top-button">
            Top button
        </button>
        <ul class="megamenu-dropdown">
            <li class="megamenu-dropdown-item">
                <a href="/link">
                    Link
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```css
#megamenu-top {
    .megamenu-top-item {
        display: flex;
        width: 20%;
        height: 5rem;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0 0.5rem;

        .megamenu-top-button {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 5px;
            border-width: 5px 0;
            margin: 1rem auto;
        }

        .megamenu-dropdown {
            display: none;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            padding: 5rem 5% 7rem;
            margin-top: 5rem;

            .megamenu-dropdown-item {
                width: 20%;
                margin: 1rem 6.66%;
                display: flex;

                a {
                    width: 100%;
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: center;
                    padding: 1rem;
                }
            }
        }

        &:hover, &:focus-within, &:active {
            .megamenu-dropdown {
                display: flex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The easiest way is to add pseudoelement to the dropdown which will take the space between the button and the dropdown. So hover will not be lost when you'll move the mouse from the button to the dropdown. I can add some example if you'll post your code

Comment: Posted some code (I always forget that stack needs 4 indents, I was stuck on the error for so long...). I tried removing some unnecessary stuff from both sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said earlier: The easiest way is to add pseudoelement to the dropdown which will take the space between the button and the dropdown. So hover will not be lost when you'll move the mouse from the button to the dropdown.
I've added background colors so you can see how it works, simply adjust sizes for your real offset

```css
#megamenu-top .megamenu-top-item {
  display: flex;
  width: 20%;
  height: 5rem;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}
#megamenu-top .megamenu-top-item .megamenu-top-button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-width: 5px 0;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}
#megamenu-top .megamenu-top-item .megamenu-dropdown {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5rem 5% 7rem;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}
#megamenu-top .megamenu-top-item .megamenu-dropdown .megamenu-dropdown-item {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 1rem 6.66%;
  display: flex;
}
#megamenu-top .megamenu-top-item .megamenu-dropdown .megamenu-dropdown-item a {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}
#megamenu-top .megamenu-top-item:hover .megamenu-dropdown, #megamenu-top .megamenu-top-item:focus-within .megamenu-dropdown, #megamenu-top .megamenu-top-item:active .megamenu-dropdown {
  display: flex;
}


/* Added code */
#megamenu-top .megamenu-top-item .megamenu-dropdown {
  background-color: #cecece;
}

/* For demo purposes */
#megamenu-top .megamenu-top-item .megamenu-dropdown {
  margin-top: 7rem;
}

/* Pseudo for dropdown */
#megamenu-top .megamenu-top-item .megamenu-dropdown::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="megamenu-top">
    <li class="megamenu-top-item">
        <button class="megamenu-top-button">
            Top button
        </button>
        <ul class="megamenu-dropdown">
            <li class="megamenu-dropdown-item">
                <a href="/link">
                    Link
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Now I understand what you meant, thanks! Using your answer and this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753252/enable-hover-on-margin helped me understand how it could be worked around! Thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting some transparent padding around each button and then have it so that when the div loses `hover` then menu disappears.

Or maybe put the buttons that appear when the menu is open into their own div and make it so that when that div is hovered over, the menu stays up.

Comment: Posted some code above. I already have padding etc and it'd also be nice to have the empty space between in-case the user wants to hide the menu. I'm basically just looking for ~0.1s delay for the display or something :D